# Is the Lie algebra generated by $e_1, e_2$ spanned by $e_1, e_2, [e_1, e_2]$?

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-algebras, stochastic-differential-equations

The Lie algebra generated by $e_1, e_2$ is spanned by the iterated Lie brackets of $e_1$ and $e_2$ ($e_1, e_2, [e_1, e_2], [e_1, [e_1, e_2]], [e_2, [e_1, e_2]], \ldots$). Is it also spanned by just $e_1, e_2$ and $[e_1, e_2]$ ?

The reason I ask is that in [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6rmander%27s_condition) the parabolic Hörmander condition is stated just with $n+1$ iterations of the Lie bracket when considering $n+1$ vector fields and in [other sources](http://www.hairer.org/papers/hormander.pdf) it is stated with an arbitrary number of iterations of the Lie bracket.

I would like to show that a particular SDE $dx = A_0(x)dt + A_1(x) dB_t$ does not satisfy the parabolic Hörmander condition and I was wondering if it would be enough to show that $A_1(x_0)$ and $[A_0, A_1](x_0)$ do not span the tangent space at a particular point $x_0$ like the Wikipedia article suggests.

Comment: There are many counterexamples. For instance, it is known that every semisimple real/complex Lie algebra can be generated by 2 elements, and of course this can be of dimension $>3$. Also the free Lie algebra on 2 generators is infinite-dimensional: not only it is not generated by these 3 elements, but one can provide explicit bases, and in particular the family of elements $\mathrm{ad}(x_1)^n(x_2)$ for $n\ge 0$ is linearly independent.

Comment: Thanks for asking this. I would love to know if it's just a typo in the Wikipedia article where the subscript "$n$" in "$j_n$" is the same as the $n$ specifying the number of vector fields. The fact that the vertical "..." has nothing vertically beneath it suggests to me that it is just a typo (i.e. unintentional double use of the same symbol).

Answer (score 5):

No, a Lie algebra generated by $e_1,e_2$ need not be spanned by $e_1,e_2,[e_1,e_2]$. For example, consider the free-nilpotent Lie algebra $L_{2,3}$ generated by $e_1,e_2$ and Lie brackets
$$
[e_1,e_2]=e_3,\; [e_1,[e_1,e_2]]=[e_1,e_3]=e_4,\; [e_2,[e_1,e_2]]=[e_2,e_3]=e_5
$$
It is $5$-dimensional, so that it cannot be spanned by three vectors alone.